# Passing variable from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp, variables

I know there are numerous questions like this but I can's seem to get them to work.  I have two jsp's and a value I wish to pass from one to another.

Code from first that gets the value:

```
 <div>
    <textarea class="field textarea small" maxlength="${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH}"
        name="${status.expression}"
        onkeyup="textCounter2(this,'${status.expression}.counter',${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH});">${status.value}</textarea>
</div>

Characters Remaining:
<input disabled class="charcounter" maxlength="4" size="4"
    value="${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH-fn:length(status.value)}"
    id="${status.expression}.counter"
    >
```

I wish to pass the value :
${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH-fn:length(status.value)}

to my second jsp

Comment: Are you including one JSP into another or are two separate views where one JSP navigates to the other?

Comment: My second jsp (the jsp where i need the value) includes the first jsp that has the value

Comment: Please post the code showing your first JSP including the second JSP and the place where you need the data from one JSP on the other one.

Comment: What's wrong with using the same `${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH-fn:length(status.value)}` in the 2nd JSP too?

Comment: It is simply included in the code with:      <%@ include file="jsp2.jsp" %>

Comment: It is calculating a value with javascript in the first and when I try to add the ${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH-fn:length(status.value)} it doesnt give the correct value. It was the value that is calculated that i need

Comment: Try adding spaces before and after minus sign. ${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH - fn:length(status.value)}

Comment: Looks like `${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH}` variable has page scope where it needs to be passed as request parameter.

Comment: Adding the space just gave the same result.  As the fnlength(status.value) is calculated in the first jsp it is 0 so it just returns the TEXT_AREA_LENGTH